# MySQL: Matching records from 2 tables with multiple values

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables:

**table1**

```
id | title     | author       | url
1  | the-test  | james-brown  | www.thetest.com
2  | the-house | clancy-brown | www.thehouse.com
3  | the-desk  | leanne-brown | www.thedesk.com
4  | the-head  | julie-brown  | www.thehead.com
```

**table2**

```
id | title     | author       | url**
1  | the-mouse | john-blue    | www.themouse.com
2  | the-house | clancy-brown | www.thehouse.com
3  | the-cups  | carrie-blue  | www.thecups.com
4  | the-head  | clancy-brown | www.thehead.com
```

I need results to show only where **both** `title` and `author` match, i.e.

```
2  | the-house | clancy-brown | www.thehouse.com
```

I've tried this:

```
select *
from table1
inner join table2 on (table1.title=table2.title) AND (table1.author=table2.author)
```

But it just runs forever (there are actually several hundred thousands rows in the real tables).

Just to note, this works fine:

```
select *
from table1
inner join table2 on (table1.title=table2.title)
```

I just can't get it to match both tables. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: have you tried: inner join table2 on (table1.title=table2.title) AND (table1.author=table2.author)

Comment: Ah, yes apologies for the typo - have now corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL is fine, you just need to index table1 and table2 on author. Add those indices and the JOIN will be fast enough. You also have an issue that you call the column `author` in your sample data and `name` in your first query.

Comment: p.s. to get the exact output you want, `SELECT table1.*` rather than `SELECT *`

Comment: To add the indexes, use: `alter table your_table add index index_name(column_name)`. Please read: [MySQL reference: `alter table` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: @Barranka or be lazy and use phpmyadmin to generate the ALTER TABLE statement for you :)

Comment: LOL :D ... lazyness is something I try to fight every single time... anyway, the OP is using MySQL workbench, so he could also alter the table using it

Comment: Thanks all. The indexing still didn't solve the problem, but by chance I noticed that all the data in one of the columns in the second table contained '\r', though it was invisible in Workbench. I reimported the data using LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' and everything now matches. So while the indexing didn't solve the problem, it's certainly a hell of a lot faster than it would have been :-). Thanks again all.